# Error after adding gem 'mithril_rails'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, mithril.js

I add gem 'mithril_rails' in my Gemfile, make `bundle install` and `bundle update`, add `//= require mithril` in my `application.js` file, type `rails s` and get error:

> /Users/myusername/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/mithril_rails-0.0.7/lib/mithril_rails/rails/engine.rb:5:in `block in <class:Engine>': undefined method`register_engine' for
>   nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

I use rails 4.2.3, mongoid.

What can I do?

Comment: Did you restart Rails server?

Comment: Of course, error occurs is when the server starts

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'sprockets 2.12.3'. The issue relating to sprockets and already reported.